# how can I set an "autoclosing" for Gtk.info_dialog in Julia?

Tags: julia, gtk

```
using Gtk

Gtk.info_dialog("this is an info dialog" )
```

it expects to be close with a mouse click on the close bottom, and I need it to close automatically so the script keeps running.

the dialog will be autoclosed.